# firebase.initializeApp callback/promise?

Tags: javascript, web, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my web page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Calcolo Diliuzioni</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>My app</h1>

        <!-- Libreria per gestire l'autenticazione con google -->
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

        <!-- Firebae config -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/live/3.0/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
        apiKey: "",
        authDomain: "",
        databaseURL: "",
        storageBucket: "",
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            if (user) {
                console.log(user);
            } else {
                console.log(user);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Let's assume I have an already logged user. When I load the page in the console I got `null`. While I'm expecting to have the current user's object.

If I run the same code in the browser console

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
if (user) {
    console.log(user);
} else {
    console.log(user);
}
```

I'm able to get the current user's object.

I think that the `firebase.initializeApp(config);` has some async behavior. What's the right way to work around it? Should I use a promise or something on the `firebase.initializeApp(config);` function? A sort of callback..

Comment: have you seen this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users ? it covers your case

Answer (score 20, accepted):

initialize app is synchronous. However, determining the current user state is asynchronous. The right way to determine the current auth state is to use an observer:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in and currentUser will no longer return null.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: what if the state changed after loading firebase and before i add this handler?  or if the state never changes?

Comment: This listener triggers on initialization too.

Answer (score 10):

I would combine two methods together:

```
function canActivate(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
            resolve(true);
        } else {
            const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
                unsubscribe();
                if (user) {
                    resolve(true);
                } else {
                    resolve(false);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

At SPA, if user already login and user can go to any pages get `firebase.auth().currentUser == true`.
But if user reload page, get `firebase.auth().currentUser == false`.
User need to wait `firebase.initializeApp(config);` finished, so add 
`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to wait init finished.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution